# Read and Write to HFS using ubuntu but hfsprogs wont install

Tags: hfs+

I am trying to read a hard drive from a Mac. The other answered questions say to install hfsprogs. The problem is when I try to install it, it says the package cannot be found. Is that package going by a different name now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try searching for it:

```
apt search hfs
```

on xenial I found `hfsplus`

Comment: and this package solves your problem?

Comment: Yes and running "sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdc2 /media"
allowed me to mount the drive